# Azure data explorer- Restrict table and records

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

We have a requirement in Kusto/ADX where we need to provide access to only one table and for certain records if conditions are met for a group or a User.

I have explored RLS and Restricted view Access on this, however below is my stands

1. RLS & Restricted view access can not be applied together on a same table
2. RLS can restrict user only on records basis and not table level
3. Restricted View access can restrict table level but not records. Also this has a pain point, I should apply restrict view policy to all other table and add restricted viewer access role to those users whom we don't restrict. For a single group/user to access one table, doing all these change seems to be painful.

Do we have any other best approach to handle this scenario?

Thank you.
Bharath Kumar B

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the tables into multiple databases, and each database will have a different set of users who can view the data.

On top of that, you'll need to apply RLS (Row Level Security) on tables, where you want some users to get only some of the records.